# What does rm -rf do?

Tags: files, directory, delete

What does `rm -rf` do when used to remove files or directories?

How do the `-r` and `-f` options work together?

Comment: How come [this hasn't been asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542441/what-does-rf-in-rm-rf-stand-for)?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Because it's trivially answered by reading the man page, which should be anyone's first port of call to answer a question like this.

Comment: Try it and see. (Spoiler: don't.)

Comment: Upvoting because the empirical approach isn't recommended, plus there's some special behaviour associated with trying to do this with the root directory.

Comment: @noonand: you probably rather meant "to **suppress** the French language... and everything else downhill from it" !  ;-D  Warf ! Warf ! you got my +1 for good humor.

Comment: By Golly ! This question must be a prank from DevRobot ! How could you possibly make it to your karma level without ever consulting the man pages. Now... are you human ?!

Comment: Totally reads like a prank indeed. As if someone tried to ask, "is rain made of H2O?" *(A good answer would be: Normally yes, but in future, once man will have been destroyed half of the flora of the Earth, 50% of it will have turned to acid (as in acid rain))*

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The command `rm -rf` is the same as `rm -r -f`.

From `rm`'s man page (type `man rm` in a terminal to see it) `-r` does:

```
remove directories and their contents recursively
```

And `-f` does:

```
ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

So in combination they do both.

#### In fact it is a very dangerous command because it will recursively remove everything within the directory you choose (or just remove the file you choose), and it will do so without ever prompting you.

**Please use this command with care!**

Comment: @Paul, what would the slash do? I use this command to remove dirs often and w/o a slash.

Comment: @Octopus, slash by itself indicates the root directory.  `rm -rf /` will theoretically delete every file on your computer that resides in a directory you have write permission for.  If you're root, that means wiping out the entire system.  (In practice, it doesn't work because GNU `rm` has a special case that refuses to allow `rm -r /` unless you also say `--no-preserve-root`.)

Comment: All the same, I don't recommend trying `rm -rf /` to see if it's caught properly.

Comment: @cjm That is what VMs and snapshots are for.

Comment: @mattburnett It's dangerous in a VM too: you may have mounts that aren't local to the VM. In particular, I believe it's fairly common to mount one of the host machine's directories on the VM to share files between the host and the VM.

Comment: @hvd That it true, but it is trivial to disconnect the network adapter(s) and removable media from a VM. And anyone who has VMs likely has a "quarantined" VM for running unknown executables.

Comment: @cjm: So does Solaris rm. And as of recently, OpenBSD rm. (Apparently it's even a POSIX requirement?)

Comment: @mattburnett I have VMs. I don't have a quarantined VM. I just don't run unknown executables. :)

Comment: @Octopus Sorry but can't say.  rm seems to have been run against my comment...

Comment: find -delete is also dangerous

Answer (score 28):

In addition to the previous correct answer, I would like to teach you how to fish:

When you are not sure about how a command works, what options has and what it does, open a terminal and type

```
man <command>
```

For example:

```
man rm
```

Once in there, you can search for the option. A man page can be really long to read, so in the terminal type:

```
/<pattern>
```

So for example, doing:

```
/-f
```

You can easily land to:

```
-f, --force
              ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

After typing `/-r` you'll get:

```
-r, -R, --recursive
              remove directories and their contents recursively
```

You can move between search results using `n` (next) and `N` (previous).

#### Bonus:

If you need to do something, but you don't know the command name, use `apropos` to search in man pages:

```
apropos <pattern>
```

For example:

```
apropos directory listing
```

Answer (score 9):

`rm` is short for remove. 
The `r` flag is to remove directories and their contents recursively and the `f` means force, and it overrides any confirmation prompts.

Comment: Strictly speaking `r flag is to remove directories ` is not right..it removes directories along with its contents, it is a recursive operation..according to your words, it would only remove the directories, what about the subdirs, files under it ? as directory entry contains name-inode mapping only, this only does not make any sense..

Comment: You are right, I will edit my answer.

Comment: -r removes directories *and their contents* recursively.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been mentioned, `rm -rf <ARG>` is meant to forcefully remove files recursively, where `<ARG>` is a directory ( though it can be a file just fine).

The whole point of `-r` ( recursive removal ) is that `rm` cannot remove directories if they aren't empty, simply because the underlying system call which `rm` uses ( [unlink](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) ) operates only on empty directories. Thus, what `-r` flag does, is [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) descending into directories and removing files first, and only then when directory is empty - it will remove it. This same effect is achieved via `find` command with `-delete` flag (when you don't specify filtering by `-type`, but that's another story).

As for `-f`, it does two things - one prevents prompting for whether you want to remove the file or not (such as when you are removing a file owned by another user from within your directory, it won't show `rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'f1'?` confirmation prompt), and ignores non-existing files. So for instance, with a non-existent file name, you should get `rm: cannot remove 'nonexistent': No such file or directory` error.

See also:

- [Why is rm allowed to delete a file under ownership of a different user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226563/85039)
- [Doing an rm -rf on a massive directory tree takes hours](https://serverfault.com/q/46852/363611)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in a directory like this

```bash
.
├── AAA
│   └── file2.txt
└── BBB
    └── AAA
        └── file1.txt
```

running `rm -rf AAA` will produce

```bash
.
└── BBB
    └── AAA
        └── file1.txt
```

It's always better check on dummy folders with `rm` if you re not sure 101%.